# Cannot Get GWT-RPC Working Properly

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to get some server side stuff going for my GWT project. As a test I tried to add in a com.sun.jmx.snmp.SnmpOid object which isn't supported by GWT run-time into my GreetingServiceImpl.java (a file that gets generated with every GWT project), but it's still saying that it's not supported.

I did the [RPC GWT tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) and when I copied the same code into that projects GreetingServiceImpl it worked fine.

I feel that I'm missing a reference or a line in an XML file. I've compared both projects thoroughly but couldn't find any discrepancies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Exact Error: `com.sun.jmx.snmp.SnmpOid is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment`

Comment: Can you post what error you're getting? Also, your second sentence might have a typo and/or is confusing.

Comment: Update question, sorry about that. Hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the source path in your .gwt.xml file. It should say something like:

```
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
```

Make sure, that your GreetingServiceImpl isn't in the source path.

If that's not the problem, please provide the exact error message you get.

**Update**

The error message you provided now, indicates that the class isn't supported by AppEngine - that's not the same as "not supported by GWT". If you don't need AppEngine, remove AppEngine support from your project (Project > Properties > Google > AppEngine > Use App Engine).

Comment: I do not have the 'server' path listed. I updated my question with the full error. Thanks for the reply!